# Images are strech in android phone. wvga800

Tags: android-layout

I have to devlop a android application. which app has alredy develped as a iphone application.
I have all images used for iphone application.

In my application, in the first screen I have to set 2 images. they are 640 x 684 and 640 x236

my emulator size is wvga800. (440*800)
but when I run the application via emulator. The first image shows as strech and it has been overlaped by 2nd image.

I used a relative layer.
here is the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/main_image"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/presshereclick" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:contentDescription="@string/main_image"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/main_image"
            android:src="@drawable/presshere" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have planned to resiz images as they fit to screen size (440*800) but I feel this can be handle from coding side. this is my 3 rd day with android.

please help me to solve this.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

When using `RelativeLayout` there is no meaning to orientation tag. You need to use relative tags. for your isue, you want the `FrameLayout` to be below the upper `ImageView` use `android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"` in your `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I tried your answere but still images are squeezed. doesn't the image size(640) causes to this? and what is px = dp * (dpi / 160). how do we get dpi values. I use wvga800 emulator.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you a better answer now, but I think you have to start with reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
Also try to move your images to a matching drawable folder for example "drawable-hdpi"